# Subfolder in res folder not finding image

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I'm attempting to load a bitmap image from an images folder from within the res folder using - `Bitmap.getBitmapResource("/images/bg_general.png")`

But the image is not being found even though it exists at specified path. Im using blackberry eclipse plugin. Here is a snippet of my dir structure where the image is located -

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bitmap.getBitmapResource("bg_general.png")` is the correct way to display the images. It works for me. Also, check whether the image is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Try
Bitmap.getBitmapResource("bg_general.png")

I think the file system is basically flattened in the cod file.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check ["Bitmap.getBitmapResource - How to navigate through a folder hierarchy to refer to a PNG file."](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Bitmap-getBitmapResource-How-to-navigate-through-a-folder/m-p/551206)

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap.getBitmapResource("images/bg_general.png");
```

remove the first `/`, the `getBitmapResource` function works with the res-folder as `baseURL`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it Searches for the file name automatically....
logically/makes sence to me it would be:

Bitmap logo = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("src/001.png");

or

Bitmap logo = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("res/001.png");

but just saying "001.png" is enough

Bitmap logo = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("001.png");